# JavaScript if statement alternative syntax

Tags: javascript, performance

I want to check the size of the screen and toggle a class depending on the size of the screen.

Html

```
<div id="item" class="test"></div>
```

Script

```
window.addEventListener("load", toggleClass);
window.addEventListener("resize", toggleClass);


function toggleClass() {

  var w = window.innerWidth;
  item = document.getElementById("item");

  if ( w > 700 ) {
    item.classList.remove("test");
  }else {
    if ( item.classList.contains("test")) {    
    }else {
      item.classList.add("test");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you rewrite the title question so that it is useful for other users?

Comment: How do you suggest?

Comment: I would recommend something like, "JavaScript if statement alternative syntax" or "Javascript if statement shorthand".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to test for whether `test` is included in the `classList` first - you can just add it unconditionally. Also, avoid implicitly creating global variables - always declare a new variable name with `var` (or, preferably, `const`, or `let`):

```
function toggleClass() {
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var item = document.getElementById("item");

  if ( w > 700 ) {
    item.classList.remove("test");
  }else {
    item.classList.add("test");
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it check to see if it is present by default? 
Even if it is inside the function, if it is not specified as var or const, it will be available for the other functions?

Comment: Generally, it's best to keep variables scoped [as narrowly as possible](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/388052/), for code clarity - given the current context, having `item`  only within the scope of this function makes the most sense

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
function toggleClass() {
    var item = document.getElementById("item");
    (window.innerWidth > 700) ? item.classList.remove("test") : item.classList.add("test");
}
```

Comment: This is really interesting. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The conditional operator is not an appropriate replacement for `if`/`else` - it is meant for when you need to conditionally have one expression or another. But here, the expression is going unused; it's orphaned. Better to leave the replacements of `if`/`else` with the conditional operator for minifiers.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach - rather than adding a class on the smaller size - use a media query to apply the styling that you want - obviously if you are using the class for a purpose other than styling - this approach may not work - but if all you are doing is styling an element based on the width of the screen - then a media query is your friend.

The benefit of this approach (if its purely styling changes you are doing) is that there is no js required - the browser will automatically use whatever styling the media query matches. This is better for performance because the re is no js to run.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 699px) {
 p {
    font-size: 14px
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
 p {
    font-size: 16px
  }
}
```

Comment: What I am doing is trying to remove a slider on the desktop. I am not very experienced, so the way I saw it was to remove the classes the slider documentation told me to include.